# Grails - Plugin view pages issue

Tags: grails, grails-plugin

I have a plugin with domain, controller and view pages. (Using grails 1.3.6)

I run the plugin as standalone, the views work fine. URL: `http://localhost:8080/sample-plugin/gp/list`. I am able to view the list page.

I installed the plugin into a main application i.e. plugin-test. Start as run-app within STS and browse to `http://localhost:8080/plugin-test/gp/list`. I am able to view the list page.

I bundle the application as war i.e. plugin-test.war and deploy to tomcat. When I browse to `http://localhost:8181/plugin-test/gp/list` I get a 404 error! I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I have been trying to resolve it for quite sometime now and still no luck. The same main application works fine in STS but not in tomcat.

`HTTP Status 404 - /plugin-test/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/gp/list.jsp`

`type Status report`

`message /plugin-test/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/gp/list.jsp`

`description The requested resource (/plugin-test/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/gp/list.jsp) is not available.`

Please help.

Thank you.

Jay Chandran.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds worryingly familiar, as I spent a while figuring out this (or a very similar) issue. I ended up raising this Grails bug report:

[Plugin layout not found in war when installed from BuildConfig.groovy](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-6980)

Have you installed the plugin as using the new BuidConfig dependency technique? The JIRA documents my workaround.

Comment: Hi Martin. thanks for your response. I am not using BuildConfig. I am installing the plugin using install-plugin command. 

My plugin-test.war has `\plugin-test\plugins\sample-plugin-01` directory which has the css, js, images files. 

And `\plugin-test\WEB-INF\plugins\sample-plugin-01\grails-app\views` has all the view pages. But tomcat does not find the view pages.

Comment: The deployed war seems to have all the required files in all the correct directories, but tomcat for some strange reason does not resolve the view pages.

Comment: I have noticed one thing today. The plugin pages are also being copied to WEB-INF/classes directory! I think this could be the reason.

Comment: WEB-INF/classes also has class files names such as `gsp_plugin_test_webapp_WEB_INF_classes_doc_header_gsp.class` That seems to be strange!

Comment: Hi.. can anyone please help me sort it... I am still having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing some of my lessons learned after experiencing the same exact issue (1.3.7):

- Double check your HTML source to make sure that your template really isn't being included. Mine was being included, but my CSS/image URLs were wrong (only while running as a war)...so I wrongly assumed that my template wasn't there.
- Don't use the ui performance tags for referencing your static content...doesn't appear to work, even if the plugin attribute is specified.
- Don't name your layout main.gsp. You're guaranteed to have conflicts.
- Don't use absolute=true on your g:resource tags. This doesn't appear to append the pluginContextPath to the absolute url, even if you specify dir="${pluginContextPath}"
- Don't use pluginContextPath, as it's no longer required: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#6.3%20Tag%20Libraries (search "Plugin Paths")
- In your g:resource tags in your plugin layout, make sure you specify the plugin attribute. Set it to the name of your plugin.
- Move your static images/css from your plugin to a web server. If each application using your plugin has its own copy, your users aren't going to benefit from caching when bouncing between apps.

Note that all of the above applies to the layout gsp in your plugin project, not your consuming application.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. This was actually a issue with STS 2.6.0 Groovy compiler. I had raised this in STS JIRA and it was fixed. Please see here: [link](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-1539)